# Issues in CUDA installation: this graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware

Tags: cuda

I tried to install CUDA 7.5 on my laptop and started to write CUDA programs. But I got an error: driver is not compatible with this version of CUDA.
My GPU is GTX 1070 and NVIDIA driver's version is 376.89. The system is win 10 64 bit. And I have installed vs 2015.

Comment: So what's your question? And why don't you install the latest version?

Comment: Install the latest driver for your GTX 1070 GPU.  That is not 376.89.  After that, install CUDA 8.0 (not CUDA 7.5) and deselect the option to install the driver bundled with the CUDA toolkit installer.  The CUDA toolkit installer may give a message like "can't find compatible hardware" but you should just select "continue" to go past that.  The latest driver will work with CUDA 8.0

Comment: I tried the latest driver 384.76 and CUDA 8.0, the problem still exists

Comment: certainly the "problem" will still exist.  If you installed 384.79, and then run the CUDA 8.0 installer, it will indicate "the graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware"  but you should be able to deselect the installation of the graphics driver in the CUDA 8 install, and continue beyond that message to a successful install of CUDA 8.

Answer (score -2):

[CUDA 7.5 doesn't support Pascal, you need CUDA 8.0.](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-8-features-revealed/)

> CUDA 8 Supports the new NVIDIA Pascal Architecture
>   A crucial goal for CUDA 8 is to provide support for the powerful new Pascal architecture, the first incarnation of which was launched at GTC 2016: Tesla P100. For full details on P100 and the Pascal GP100 GPU architecture, check out the blog post “Inside Pascal”. One of NVIDIA’s goals is to support CUDA across the entire NVIDIA platform, so CUDA 8 supports all new Pascal GPUs, including Tesla P100, P40, and P4, as well as NVIDIA Titan X, and Pascal-based GeForce, Quadro, and DrivePX GPUs.

Comment: I tried CUDA 8.0 and the latest driver still can not solve the problem.